# How to run a shell script when a file or directory changes?

Tags: linux, shell, inotify

I want to run a shell script when a specific file or directory changes.

How can I easily do that?

Comment: I have a post I think is basically the same : http://stackoverflow.com/q/2972765/119790

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham I'd move this to superuser, because the answer might not have anything do with programming - i.e. there might be some program or configuration option that can be used, without any programming needed. I had the same question, and searched superuser first :p

Comment: dupe https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use [inotify-tools](http://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki).

The linked Github page has a number of examples; here is one of them.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

cwd=$(pwd)

inotifywait -mr \
  --timefmt '%d/%m/%y %H:%M' --format '%T %w %f' \
  -e close_write /tmp/test |
while read -r date time dir file; do
       changed_abs=${dir}${file}
       changed_rel=${changed_abs#"$cwd"/}

       rsync --progress --relative -vrae 'ssh -p 22' "$changed_rel" \
           usernam@example.com:/backup/root/dir && \
       echo "At ${time} on ${date}, file $changed_abs was backed up via rsync" >&2
done
```

Comment: [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) is another option.

Comment: fanotify is another option. Builded on top of inotify. It has some improvements to inotify, for example it can notify file changes within a specific directory.

Comment: It would be nice if this answer included the relevant information instead of being just a link.

Comment: @Darkhogg, it would be nice indeed. I had only been a member for a few weeks when I answered this question, and I did not know the site rules very well back then. In retrospect, I should have voted to close this question instead of providing a poor, link-only answer. If it ever gets unaccepted, I will delete it right away.

Comment: I don't think simply posting a link to a man page is very helpful; it'd be much better if you gave the command to install the package, and examples of common usage, and _then_ linked to the full docs if the visitor still needs more information.

Comment: @Ian, yup, this is probably my worst answer on this site. It is very old, and it is accepted so I cannot delete it. I choose to keep it unchanged as a kind of testimony about those times. I use comments now to achieve the same thing, of course, although not everyone agrees with that either.

Comment: Just a small addition, since I didn't see that here anywhere: incron is not able to monitor the subdirectories of that directory recursively. So unless you're monitoring a trivial directory, you'll find that incron is too limited. You might want to try [this alternative solution](https://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2011-01/07-watcher_a_recursive_incron_alternative)

Answer (score 71):

You may try [`entr`](https://github.com/eradman/entr) tool to run arbitrary commands when files change. Example for files:

```
$ ls -d * | entr sh -c 'make && make test'
```

or:

```
$ ls *.css *.html | entr reload-browser Firefox
```

or print `Changed!` when file `file.txt` is saved:

```
$ echo file.txt | entr echo Changed!
```

---

For directories use `-d`, but you've to use it in the loop, e.g.:

```
while true; do find path/ | entr -d echo Changed; done
```

or:

```
while true; do ls path/* | entr -pd echo Changed; done
```

Comment: `entr` is the simplest, most composable and unix-y tool for the job. Love it. `incron` can be replaced with `entr`  and a process manager like `runit`, `s6` or even `systemd`.

Comment: This. it's 10 times more simpler than inotifywait

Comment: I have a script regularly appending to a log file.  When I use `entr` to monitor that log file and `touch` the log, everything works fine, but when the script appends to the file, `entr` fails.  This may be because I have noatime set in my fstab for my ssd - but that only stops the updating of the access time not the modify time, so this confuses me.  I have then tried `entr -cdr` on the directory of files that are updated with the log.  That recognizes with the directory contents change, but the `-r` does not work.  The `entr` process just ends.

Comment: I turned this into [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56454520/using-entr-how-is-update-identified-noatime-troubles-and-why-does-r-not-w)

Comment: Thank you for this. Excellent. Much better than inotify or when-changed.

Comment: Github seems to be https://github.com/eradman/entr. The original entrproject.com link seems to be dead.

Comment: Adding on: `homebrew` can install entr for you.

Answer (score 37):

I use this script to run a build script on changes in a directory tree:

```
#!/bin/bash -eu
DIRECTORY_TO_OBSERVE="js"      # might want to change this
function block_for_change {
  inotifywait --recursive \
    --event modify,move,create,delete \
    $DIRECTORY_TO_OBSERVE
}
BUILD_SCRIPT=build.sh          # might want to change this too
function build {
  bash $BUILD_SCRIPT
}
build
while block_for_change; do
  build
done
```

Uses `inotify-tools`. Check `inotifywait` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) for how to customize what triggers the build.

Comment: Doesn't this have a race condition? If you change a file during the build, it won't catch it.

Comment: @FSMaxB yes, it does. If I would save any edits while it was building, I would then save one of the source files again when it was finished to trigger a new build.

Comment: Great example. I fixed your non-bash comments.

Comment: I see that this (my) answer is still being upvoted. I'd like to say that if I had to do this now, I'd use [entr](http://entrproject.org/). See the other answer.

Answer (score 10):

How about this script? Uses the 'stat' command to get the access time of a file and runs a command whenever there is a change in the access time (whenever file is accessed).

```
#!/bin/bash

while true

do

   ATIME=`stat -c %Z /path/to/the/file.txt`

   if [[ "$ATIME" != "$LTIME" ]]

   then

       echo "RUN COMMNAD"
       LTIME=$ATIME
   fi
   sleep 5
done
```

Comment: It's better to use `inotifywait` (inotify-tools) since it wakes up almost instantaneously when the file is updated. (Your script would wait up to 5 seconds before noticing.) Your script also has to wake up every 5 seconds, spawn a process, check the result and then go back to sleep, while this good enough for a "hack it together in 5 minutes"-script, it wastes CPU resources and should be avoided in production code.

Comment: Thanks you for this, I usually use `enter` but sometimes I need to do something on a system where I cannot install any tools, so a method that works on any system (well, I haven’t run into anything without `stat` is super helpful. I’m using this approach without the loop to compare two times (folder time stamp and file) to see if I need to regenerate the file, and I run the check from cron.

Comment: @VDR when the script will work....should I have to run the example script manually to check any changes in a file e.g. example.txt occurs. As I have understood, if any change occurs it will run a command/run another script...kindly clearfy

Comment: i agree with @Ibutlr sometimes we hae some machine we can not install any tool there

Comment: @TAMIMHAIDER Once you invoke the script it runs in a loop comparing the given file's access time and if it is accessed it runs `echo RUN COMMAND`. You can replace the 'echo' command with other script/command that you want to run whenever a file changes.

Comment: @VDR thanks for your ans...could you please help with this scenario > in the same directory I have a file e.g. example.war and a script e.g. testscript.sh. i want if any changes occure in example.war (update/replace) will trigger testscript.sh automatically. In your example what I have understood after every change I need to run the helper script to check example.war and then it will trigger testscript.sh.

Comment: @TAMIMHAIDER, just replace '/path/to/the/file.txt' to '/directory/where/example.war' and replace `echo "RUN COMMAND` with `testscript.sh`

Answer (score 3):

Check out the kernel filesystem monitor daemon

http://freshmeat.net/projects/kfsmd/

Here's a how-to:

http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/124903

Comment: The second link is broken

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, inotify-tools is probably the best idea. However, if you're programming for fun, you can try and earn hacker XPs by judicious application of [tail -f](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tail) .

Comment: Interesting, but how do you do this? tail -f is a blocking instruction, we need it to return in order to launch a script?

Comment: @pdem read it's output - any output would mean the file's changed. I'm not sure what it does if the file *shrinks* though

Answer (score 2):

Just for debugging purposes, when I write a shell script and want it to run on save, I use this:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="$1" # Name of file
command="${*:2}" # Command to run on change (takes rest of line)
t1="$(ls --full-time $file | awk '{ print $7 }')" # Get latest save time
while true
do
  t2="$(ls --full-time $file | awk '{ print $7 }')" # Compare to new save time
  if [ "$t1" != "$t2" ];then t1="$t2"; $command; fi # If different, run command
  sleep 0.5
done
```

Run it as

```
run_on_save.sh myfile.sh ./myfile.sh arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Edit: Above tested on Ubuntu 12.04, for Mac OS, change the ls lines to:

```
"$(ls -lT $file | awk '{ print $8 }')"
```

Comment: this might be improved with the `watch` command, but I like this implementation. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to ~/.bashrc:

```
function react() {
    if [ -z "$1" -o -z "$2" ]; then
        echo "Usage: react <[./]file-to-watch> <[./]action> <to> <take>"
    elif ! [ -r "$1" ]; then
        echo "Can't react to $1, permission denied"
    else
        TARGET="$1"; shift
        ACTION="$@"
        while sleep 1; do
            ATIME=$(stat -c %Z "$TARGET")
            if [[ "$ATIME" != "${LTIME:-}" ]]; then
                LTIME=$ATIME
                $ACTION
            fi
        done
    fi
}
```

Comment: Use `ATIME=$(stat -f %m "$TARGET")` on MacOS and `ATIME=$(stat -c %Y "$TARGET")` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Quick solution for fish shell users who wanna track a single file:

```
while true
    set old_hash $hash
    set hash (md5sum file_to_watch)
    if [ $hash != $old_hash ]
        command_to_execute
    end
    sleep 1
end
```

replace `md5sum` with `md5` if on macos.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option: http://fileschanged.sourceforge.net/

See especially "example 4", which "monitors a directory and archives any new or changed files".

Answer (score 1):

`inotifywait` can satisfy you.

Here is a common sample for it:

```
inotifywait -m /path -e create -e moved_to -e close_write | # -m is --monitor, -e is --event
    while read path action file; do
        if [[ "$file" =~ .*rst$ ]]; then             # if suffix is '.rst'
            echo ${path}${file} ': '${action}        # execute your command
            echo 'make html'
            make html
        fi
    done
```

Comment: But how do you terminate it ?

Comment: @KalibZen You don't; in this mode, it runs forever. You can terminate the job with ctrl-C or similar, of course.

Comment: @tripleee it's ok, I use file flag to stop it, or write function to product a file that contains stop flag. `flag=$(echo file_content)`. `if [ flag == 'stop' ] then exit 1`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to run `rake test` every time you modify any ruby file ("*.rb") in **app/** and **test/** directories.

Just get the most recent modified time of the watched files and check every second if that time has changed.

**Script code**

```
t_ref=0; while true; do t_curr=$(find app/ test/ -type f -name "*.rb" -printf "%T+\n" | sort -r | head -n1); if [ $t_ref != $t_curr ]; then t_ref=$t_curr; rake test; fi; sleep 1; done
```

**Benefits**

- You can run any command or script when the file changes.
- It works between any filesystem and virtual machines (shared folders on VirtualBox using Vagrant); so you can use a text editor on your Macbook and run the tests on Ubuntu (virtual box), for example.

**Warning**

- The `-printf` option works well on Ubuntu, but do not work in MacOS.