# monitor folder and execute command

Tags: shell, automation, virtualbox

I'm looking for a solution for monitoring a folder for new file creation and then execute shell command upon the created file. The scenario is I have a host machine that runs a virtual machine and they share a folder. What I want is when I create or copy a new file to that shared folder on my host machine, on the VM, the system should be able to detect those changes. I have tried incron and inotify but they only work when I do the copy, create as a user in the VM. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1** in this answer may help: [Bash script, watch folder, execute command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6475265/520398) 
Just run that script in your VM, and you should be able to detect changes made by the host.