# How to find if there are new files in a directory every 2 minutes in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a directory called `/home/user/local`. Every two minutes or so, a new file is dumped into this directory. I need to check this directory every 2 minutes to see if a new file/files have landed in there. And if there are new files, I need to put a list of it into a variable to use later on. How do I do this shell script?

Answer (score 6):

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

FILELIST=/tmp/filelist
MONITOR_DIR=/home/usr/local

[[ -f ${FILELIST} ]] || ls ${MONITOR_DIR} > ${FILELIST}

while : ; do
    cur_files=$(ls ${MONITOR_DIR})
    diff <(cat ${FILELIST}) <(echo $cur_files) || \
         { echo "Alert: ${MONITOR_DIR} changed" ;
           # Overwrite file list with the new one.
           echo $cur_files > ${FILELIST} ;
         }

    echo "Waiting for changes."
    sleep $(expr 60 \* 2)
done
```

a quick & dirty way. :)  It'll monitor the directory for changes, not only when there's new file dumped in, but also if some file is missing/deleted.

File list is stored in variable `$cur_files`.

Answer (score 2):

`inotifywait` is exactly what you are looking for: http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait

Comment: Yes but not working with Windows share CIFS mounted on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a cron job that runs a script that takes the current listing and compares it to an older listing stored in a file somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your variable is called $listOF

Create a script:

```
listOfFiles=`ls -t /home/user/local`
for i in $listOfFiles
do
echo "$listOF" | grep $i
if [[ "$?" -eq "0" ]]
then
listOF=$listOF" "$i
fi
done
```

And put this script into the crontab by cmd: crontab -e
in format:

```
1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47,49,51,53,55,57,59 * * * * <path to your script>
```

Comment: I think you can write the `crontab` entry like this: `0-59/2 * * * * <path to your script>`

Comment: Yes, you can, but sometimes it works, sometimes no. :-) Depends on distribution, version, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First off a big thank you to leafei, I'd hoped that it was that easy. However for my devices writing temporary files for loops wasn't portable enough for my current [project](https://github.com/S0AndS0/Perinoid_Pipes) and I required performing actions for various things that might happen within a monitored directory, so here's the script I wrote based off leafei's answer and tested locally. Note formatting maybe off on first post...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
Var_monitor_dir="${1?No directory passed}"
Var_sleep_time="${2:-120}"
Var_diff_opts="--suppress-common-lines"
Func_parse_change(){
    _added_input="$(grep -E ">" <<<"${@}")"
    _removed_input="$(grep -E "<" <<<"${@}")"
    if [ "${#_added_input}" != "0" ]; then
            mapfile -t _arr_added <<<"${_added_input}"
            let _added_count=0
            until [ "${#_arr_removed}" = "${_added_count}" ]; do
                _current_path="${_arr_removed[${_added_count}]}"
                if [ -f "${_current_path}" ]; then
                    echo "# ${0##*/} detected added file: ${_current_path}"
                elif [ -d "${_current_path}" ]; then
                    echo "# ${0##*/} detected added directory ${_current_path}"
                elif [ -p "${_current_path}" ]; then
                    echo "# ${0##*/} detected added named pipe ${_current_path}"
                fi
                ## Ignore other added input and add to index counter
                let _added_count++
            done
            unset _added_count
    fi
    if [ "${#_removed_input}" != "0" ]; then
            mapfile -t _arr_removed <<<"${_added_input}"
            let _removal_count=0
            until [ "${#_arr_removed}" = "${_removal_count}" ]; do
                echo "# Removal detected: ${_arr_removed[${_removal_count}]}"
                let _removal_count++
            done
    fi
 }
 Func_watch_dir(){
    _current_listing=""
    while [ -d "${Var_monitor_dir}" ]; then
         _new_listing="$(ls "${Var_monitor_dir}")"
         _diff_listing="$(diff ${Var_diff_opts} <(echo "${_current_listing}") <(echo "${_new_listing}"))"
        if [ "${#_diff_listing}}" != "0" ]; then
            Func_parse_change "${_diff_listing}"
        fi
        _current_listing="${_new_listing}"
        sleep ${Var_sleep_time}
    done
}
if [ "${#@}" != "0" ]; then
     Func_watch_dir
     exit 0
else
     echo "${0##*/} needs a directory to monitor"
     exit 1
if
```

Assuming the above is saved as `monitor_directory.sh` and the directory to be monitored is `/tmp` then opening one terminal and inputting `monitor_directory "/tmp"` (or `monitor_directory.sh "/tmp" "10"` to have faster updates between tests) will start the loop that checks for changes. Then opening a second terminal try inputting the following and waiting for the first terminal to update

```
mkdir -p /tmp/test_dir
touch /tmp/test.file
```

After the wait time is up the first terminal should report that a file and a directory has appeared, if you run the following and wait again it'll show removals too.

```
rmdir /tmp/test_dir
rm /tmp/test.file
```

Hope this helps some.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know when a new folder or file comes with starting "app-". You can use this script.

```
#!/bin/bash
yourfilenames=`ls /home/anulal/folder/ | grep app-`
if [ -n "$yourfilenames" ]; then
  echo "yes"
else
  echo "no"
fi
```

This will print yes if a new file or folder came with name starting "app-" and no if no folder is there with name starting "app-".