# Trigger a command in ubuntu/linux whenever a new file is created in a directory

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, s3cmd

How could I trigger a command in ubuntu/linux, whenever a new file is created in a directory by a Java webapp ?

Usage/Context:
I need to move a newly created file (created by java app), in a directory to amazon s3 using `s3cmd` command.

Comment: You need to use Directory watcher. Here is a link to tutorial: http://java.dzone.com/news/how-watch-file-system-changes

Comment: I think I would need this watcher at the linux end instead of, at java end. In fact java itself is responsible for/ making those changes.

Comment: hmm...So, looks like you have to work with shell scripting. Look if following link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060212/in-linux-how-do-i-run-a-shell-script-when-a-file-or-directory-changes