# What is the best way to use Laravel route in Vue JS component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a vue js component which makes an axios request to a laravel route. But in the vue files I don't have access to the `route()` function and have to use static url's for now. 
Here's some code:
web.php:

```
// API
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {
    // GET
    Route::get('/brands', 'BrandsController@getBrands')->name('api-get-brands');
    Route::get('/{brand_id}/models', 'BrandsController@getModels')->name('api-get-models');
    Route::get('/fuel-types', 'BrandsController@getFuelTypes')->name('api-get-fuel-types');
    Route::get('/gearboxes', 'BrandsController@getGearboxes')->name('api-get-gearboxes');
});
```

Vue component:

```
methods: {
            getBrands: function() {
                let app = this
                axios.get('/api/brands')
                    .then(function(response) {
                        app.brands = response.data
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
            },
            ...
```

}

It works now but I wonder if that's the best way or is there some better way to do it

Comment: I've had a decent bit of success using [this package](https://github.com/aaronlord/laroute) and assigning into a `window` variable.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy that package looks good. I guess you need to run `php artisan laroute:generate` every time you change routes?

Comment: @ljubadr Yeah, pretty much. That's really my only gripe

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thanks! I guess some kind of watcher can be set to run the command :) I guess something like this could be useful [In Linux, how do I run a shell script when a file or directory changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060212/in-linux-how-do-i-run-a-shell-script-when-a-file-or-directory-changes)

Comment: @ljubadr I've been down that road, too. I would suggest [using this package](https://github.com/jasonlewis/resource-watcher) to watch your `routes` directory for changes. In the callback of the listener you can run `Artisan::call('laroute:generate')` to have the route file regenerated. You can then have `npm run watch` or `npm run hot` running, which will auto-recompile your JS including the new routes, as long as you're doing something like `require('routes.js`)` somewhere in your javascript.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - wow, this is awesome, thanks a lot! I'll put it to a good use :) Cheers!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can pass the route as props to the component inside the blade file.

Inside the view:

```
<component home-route="{{ route('home') }}"></component>
```

Inside the vue component:

```
<script> 
    export default {
        props: ['homeRoute'],
    }
</script>
```

Then you can access the route inside the component like so:

```
this.homeRoute
```

You can learn more about props here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: But if i want to use route that requires a parameter ?

Comment: @john <component home-route="{{ route('home', $parameters) }}"></component>

Comment: @SamuelAialaFerreira what if parameters should be passed from the vue app?

Comment: @Yerke don't know what you mean unfortunately :(

Comment: They mean 'What if the $parameters variable needs to come from the Vue app and is not known when the page first loads?'

Answer (score 3):

The only way how to use routes with parameters that I found out is like this:

**The route:**

```
Route::get('route/{param1}/{param2}', [Controller::class, 'actionName'])->name('routeName');
```

**The blade:**

```
<component :route="'{{ route('routeName', ["", ""]) }}'"></component>
```

where the number of empty strings in the array is equal to the number of required parameters for the route.

**The component:**

```
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        route: String
    },
    data() {
        return {
            param1: "",
            param2: ""
        }
    },
    computed: {
        fullRoute() {
            return this.route + '/' + this.param1 + '/' + this.param2;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I am using Laravel 8 and Vue 3.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/tighten/ziggy

> Ziggy provides a JavaScript route() helper function that works like Laravel's, making it easy to use your Laravel named routes in JavaScript.

You can then use routes in JS just like in PHP

```
route('posts.index');
```

With parameters too

```
route('posts.show', [1]);
```