# Shell script to unzip files using file watcher

Tags: linux, bash, shell, job-scheduling, autosys

I have started working on Linux recently. I'm looking for a solution for monitoring a folder for zipped files and unzip them. I have created a simple script(say unzip.sh) to unzip the files but there is no fix time at which zipped are received, so I want to use a script that checks for zipped files and calls this unzip.sh script if found any zipped files. Thanks.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd <dir name>
for i in `find . -name "*.gz"`; do
    gunzip $i
done
```

Comment: You can use `inotifywait` to do things only when new files are placed inside a folder. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/959040/652023).

Comment: you can use schedule the script in `crontab`.

Comment: [How to run a shell script when a file or directory changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4060212/608639) and friends like [linux bash filesystem notification](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+bash+filesystem+notification).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

crontab is what you need

Build a simple textfile like this:

```
*/5 * * * * bash /path/to/your/script.sh
```

Assuming you called this file my.cron, then you can install it with

```
crontab my.cron
```

The script will then run every 5 minutes.
here some more examples: https://crontab.guru/examples.html

Stop it again with

```
crontab -r
```