# How to detect an event as soon as it happens on an external component. Don't want to poll, any alternatives?

Tags: java, python, algorithm, scala, events

I don't want to use polling technique or any library which underneath uses polling, things like Thread.sleep etc. Any suggestions? 
This is an open ended question I am just interested in approach.

Examples : Pulling up a file from FTP as soon as it lands up there, etc.

Comment: Then something needs to push events.

Comment: How much control do you have on the server?

Comment: If we take example of FTP, FTP can't push the events, in that case, is polling only available option?

Comment: FTP doesn't have push events, but that doesn't mean that you cannot run a small non-FTP server w/ push capabilities alongside your FTP if you don't want to rely on polling...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060212/how-to-run-a-shell-script-when-a-file-or-directory-changes

Comment: I voted to close this question as too ... openended :)
In general, everything, that starts with "I don't want to use ..."  is a clear indicatiion of an XY-problem

Answer (score 1):

In principle, there's no way around

- either you poll (proactive)
- or "server" pushes event to you (reactive)

Obviously, there's ways to wrap polling into reactive-like interfaces.

Regarding ftp – the alternatives is making service-in-the-middle that does pushing, or using `inotify` (which may wrap it for you effectively)