# Shell Script Entry(path() Changes when i move them to Certain Directory

Tags: shell

I have a path say ==========================

## /nfs/old_home/dexter/work/Deamon/Test2/IN/

Inside this path i have script files say:
Files1.sh
Files2.sh
Flles3.sh
....

## Filesn.sh

Each of these script files have a line say

export DATABASE_XML=/mnt/nfs/lin_work_live/linear_work/dexter/Deamon/Test2/RDB.xml

=====================================================
So say the first path i.e. /nfs/old_home/dexter/work/Deamon/Test2/ has this RDB.xml file and the path Given in that Script file i.e. 
export DATABASE_XML=**/mnt/nfs/lin_work_live/linear_work/dexter/Deamon/Test2/**RDB.xml
is the linked path.

So If i move the script files from say 
/nfs/old_home/dexter/work/Deamon/Test2/IN/ to /nfs/old_home/dexter/work/Deamon/Test3/IN/ so it should read the RDB.xml file of the /nfs/old_home/dexter/work/Deamon/Test3/ directory and not the Test2..in 1 simple word the path inside the scripts 
export DATABASE_XML=/mnt/nfs/lin_work_live/linear_work/dexter/Deamon/**Test2**/RDB.xml
Should change to Test3 also this change should reflect in all the File1.sh...FileN.sh files i move.
Hope this is much clear now??

Comment: You have a file `/dir1/script1` containing variable `/dir2/file2`. You move it into `/dir3/script1` and want the variable to change to `/dir4/file2`. When you are in some undeclared directory `/dir5`, running the command `pwd -P` somehow returns a relative link to a file `dir6/file2` rather than an absolute path to a directory. I think you need to fix up your question to explain how `pwd -P` can return a file and you need to explain the relationship between `dir1`/`dir2` and `dir3`/`dir4`.

Comment: Pleas refer the question again and lemme know if i am clear now.

Comment: You still haven't explained how `/dir1` (`/nfs/old_home/dexter/work/Deamon/Test2/`) relates to `/dir2` (`/mnt/nfs/lin_work_live/linear_work/dexter/Deamon/Test2/`) - nor `/dir3` with `/dir4`. Is one just a symlink'd version of the other? Is `.../Test2/IN` a real subdirectory of `.../Test2` or can it be a symlink?

Comment: /nfs/old_home/dexter/work/Deamon/Test2/ >> org Dir  /mnt/nfs/lin_work_live/linear_work/dexter/Deamon/Test2/ >> Simlink of above........./nfs/old_home/dexter/work/Deamon/Test3/ >> Diff Directory.................../mnt/nfs/lin_work_live/linear_work/dexter/Deamon/Test3/ >>> Symlink of Test3.....just want the path changed from Test2 > Test3...in this line  export DATABASE_XML=**/mnt/nfs/lin_work_live/linear_work/dexter/Deamon/Test2/**RDB.xml.....When i move the files from Test2 >>  Test3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### restatement of the problem

- there are some files in folder `/orig`

  - there is a configuration file `/orig/conf`
  - there are some scripts `/orig/IN/script1` .. `/orig/IN/scriptN`

    - each script contains a line: `export VAR="/orig-sym/conf"`
  - `/orig-sym` is a symbolic link to `/orig`
- the files are copied to a new folder `/new`

  - the config file moves from `/orig/conf` to `/new/conf`
  - scripts move from `/orig/IN/scriptX` to `/new/IN/scriptX`

    - change relevant lines to `export VAR="/new-sym/conf"`
  - `/new-sym` is a symbolic link to `/new`

### solution 1

Do a search & replace on the files `scriptX` after they have been moved.

Something along the lines of `sed -i s/find/replace/ file*` can work but care must be taken to sure `replace` does not contain characters that are special to sed (eg. `/`, `[`, etc). Quoting these safely can be complicated.

However, we can sidestep the issue. For example, using the shell and perl:

```
$ mkdir "/new"
$ ln -s "/new" "/new-sym"
$ cp -R "/orig/." "/new"
$ perl -i -pe '
  BEGIN { $replacement = shift }
  s/^(export VAR)=.*/$1="$replacment"/
' "/new-sym" "/new/IN/"script*
```

- create the new folder and the symlink to it
- copy the files into the new folder
- run a perl script to do search and replace

  - first argument is replacement symlink path (`/new-sym`)
  - remaining arguments are the files to change
  - `-i` overwrites files
  - `BEGIN` copies the new path avoiding the escaping complications
  - `s///` performs the replacement

    - **Note:** check that only desired lines match

### solution 2

Don't use absolute paths.

As the configuration file is always one level up from the scripts,  relative paths won't need to be changed.

If the script is executed directly, `$0` should contain its path.
So in many situations, something like this will work:

```
#!/bin/sh
# scriptX

# ...
# commands that must not include "cd", "pushd", etc
# ...

top=$(dirname -- "$0")
absolute_top=$(CDPATH= cd -- "$top" && pwd -P)

# ...
# commands that may include "cd", "pushd", etc
# ...

export VAR="$(absolute_top)/../conf
```

Comment: well i already use a sed command to do that i.e. sed -i 's/Orig\/ReissueDatabase/new\/ReissueDatabase/g' Script1.sh...after i move the files to the new location......isn't there something that can automatically change the path as soon i move them to new from original directory.....i mean running the sed script is the regular thing i do just want to automate things up...i hope you get mee??