# `entr`: How is update ID'd? noatime troubles? &, why -r not work with -d?

Tags: inotify, ctime

I have a script regularly appending to a log file. When I use `entr` (discovered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38229197/1618452)) to monitor that log file, and I then touch the log, everything works fine, but when the script appends to the file, `entr` fails. This may be because I have noatime set in my fstab - but that only stops the updating of the access time not the modify time, so this confuses me.

I've checked and while atime is not updating, ctime (`ls -lc`) definitely is. Could `entr` really be depending on atime?  I use noatime because I have an SSD.  So what should I do?  I just stumbled on [lazytime](https://lwn.net/Articles/621046/).  Would that solve the problem?

Since monitoring the log file was not working, I tried `entr -cdr` on the directory of files that are updated (a new file is created) at the same time as the log (the log is in a different directory). `entr` recognizes when the directory contents change, but the -r does not work. The `entr` process just ends, saying "entr: directory altered".

Any idea how to fix this or whether I should just go back to inotify, would be appreciated.

**Edit**: I have written it with inotify now, and the event reported when the log file is written to is, sensibly enough, "MODIFY."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that `entr` does not respond to IN_MODIFY events, but only to these (in Linux):

```
IN_CLOSE_WRITE|IN_DELETE_SELF|IN_MOVE_SELF|IN_CREATE
```

Also, IN_ATTRIB, but only if the file-mode or inode numbers change.

In BSD/OSX, it's:

```
NOTE_DELETE|NOTE_WRITE|NOTE_RENAME|NOTE_TRUNCATE|NOTE_ATTRIB
```

Also, the option `-r` has no effect in the context of the `-d` option.  It only works when `entr` is monitoring files.

See the developer's [comments](https://bitbucket.org/eradman/entr/issues/82/update-not-recognized-and-r-not-working#comment-52489331).  Also, [more info](http://eradman.com/entrproject/) on entr.