# detecting directory changes with entr

Tags: linux, bash, shell, systemd

I want to run a command each time a directory is updated (new/changed file within). I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060212/how-to-run-a-shell-script-when-a-file-or-directory-changes) suggesting `entr`. I've made a script applying `entr` but it doesn't seem to work as intended.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
ls -d * /Users/me/test | entr echo hey
```

when I run the script it echos "hey" once, but if I add new files to `test` stdout just hangs without echoing another "hey".

Comment: Check the second part of the answer you've linked : for directories, add `-d` to `entr` and put it in a loop

Comment: If you only want to monitor `/Users/me/test`, you just need `echo /Users/me/test | entr -d echo hey`

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting to use `systemd` **[path units](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html)**.

Here is a [tutorial](https://www.putorius.net/systemd-path-units.html) about monitoring a path unit.

And here is a more [general explanation of `systemd` units](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files).

#### Advantages of of `systemd` path units:

1. Most flexible
2. Decouples event management from action management from run-time control
3. Strong central logging and auditing
4. Standard location and information about `systemd` units
5. Standard for event management and action management

#### Disadvantages of `systemd` path units:

1. Complex
2. Requires admin permissions
3. Depends on `systemd`