# How to check when a file has been changed in linux?

Tags: linux, file, events, command-line

I have a Linux command line program.

It produces output to a file.

The output file is modified continuously by the program after short time intervals.

Every time, the program changes the file, I want to be notified.

Is there any command line for that, or any script which could help me?

Comment: "some processing". Makes your question ambiguous. Please correct.

Comment: using inotifywait: https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki or look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972765/linux-script-that-monitors-file-changes-within-folders-like-autospec-does

Answer (score 1):

I think `icrond` is what you need

The `incrond` (inotify cron daemon) is a daemon which monitors filesystem events (such as add a new file, delete a file and so on) and executes commands or shell scripts. It’s use is generally similar to `cron`.

Take a look here for some examples http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-inotify-examples-to-replicate-directories/

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

Linux: [inotify](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ubuntu-inotify/index.html) or

[File Alteration monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_alteration_monitor) or

[incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) or

[Linux audit](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html)

Also please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972765/linux-script-that-monitors-file-changes-within-folders-like-autospec-does)

Also for script you might need as follows using inotify tool.

```
while true; do
  change=$(inotifywait -e close_write,moved_to,create .)
  change=${change#./ * }
  if [ "$change" = "myfile" ]
  then 
      echo -e "my file changed"
    fi
done
```