# CMake and PC-Lint Plus - how do I pass CMake's include directory list to Lint?

Tags: cmake, lint, pc-lint

I'm trying to incorporate PC-Lint Plus into my cmake project, mainly per [PC-Lint needs a list of all include paths for the files to be scanned. How to get a list of all include paths recursively needed by a target in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068305/pc-lint-needs-a-list-of-all-include-paths-for-the-files-to-be-scanned-how-to-ge).

PC-Lint is getting invoked, but ends up dying because not all the includes are in the PC-Lint invocation.

I dumped the above link into a Lint.cmake, and included that in my top level CMake file.  In my project file, I added:

```
if(COMMAND add_pc_lint)
add_pc_lint(moded ${SRC_FILES})
endif(COMMAND add_pc_lint)
```

So I'd expect the lines:

```
function(add_pc_lint target)
    get_directory_property(lint_include_directories INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
    # let's get those elephants across the alps
    # prepend each include directory with "-i"; also quotes the directory
    set(lint_include_directories_transformed)
    foreach(include_dir ${lint_include_directories})
        list(APPEND lint_include_directories_transformed -i"${include_dir}")
    endforeach(include_dir)
```

to pull the include directory list out of `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`.

If I add:

```
message(STATUS "********************************************")
message(STATUS "Include directories - ${lint_include_directories}")
message(STATUS "********************************************")
message(STATUS "********************************************")
message(STATUS "INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES - ${INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}")
message(STATUS "********************************************")
```

directly above the foreach loop, `lint_include_directories` and `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` both appear to be empty.

What do I need to do to get the full list of include directories, including from `target_link_libraries` and `target_include_directories`, from CMake to give to PC-Lint Plus?

Comment: It sounds like when you include `Lint.cmake` from your top-level file, you lose the directory scope containing your `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` directory property. So this property is empty in the new directory scope.

Comment: @squareskittles But that casts doubt on the whole idea that this lint file can work, which it appears to be somewhat standard.. I added those message() calls in the project CMakeLists.txt and they just show the single target_include_directories() "main" directory, but none of the include directories implied by libraries in target_link_libraries().

Comment: My earlier comment was incorrect. After taking a closer look, I found what is probably the issue (please see my response). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I have updated the [CMake PC-Lint script](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/contrib/macros/PC-Lint) to account for the issue described below in my response here.

---

The [documentation](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/contrib/macros/PC-Lint) on PC-Lint usage appears to be catered for old CMake, not the target-based modern CMake. The `add_pc_lint` function grabs the **include directories** and **compile definitions** from CMake directory properties. These directories properties will be populated if your project has calls such as:

- `include_directories()`
- `add_definitions()`

Without these commands (which really should not be used in modern CMake), the `add_pc_lint` function likely won't find all the include directories and compile definitions you expect.

In modern CMake, the **include directories** and **compile definitions** are stored as properties of a *target* instead, when you use commands such as these:

- `target_include_directories()`
- `target_compile_definitions()`

In this case, you have to modify the `add_pc_lint` function to grab the properties from the **target**, not the **directory**. So, change the top of the `add_pc_lint` function from this:

```
function(add_pc_lint target)
    get_directory_property(lint_include_directories INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
    get_directory_property(lint_defines COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)
```

to this:

```
function(add_pc_lint target)
    get_target_property(lint_include_directories ${target} INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
    get_target_property(lint_defines ${target} COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)
```

Comment: Ok, this is closer.. I see the one directory specified by a "target_include_directories" line in the project's CMakeLists.txt - but where do I get the full list of directories implied by pulling in "target_link_libraries"?  This project compiles, so it can clearly see the list of directories, but I don't know how to get that list to give to lint.  If I look in the generated Makefile, CXX_INCLUDES contains the list of includes - how do I get that out of CMake?

Comment: @bizaff You likely have to call `add_pc_lint` on each target that you link to in `target_link_libraries()`. It becomes even more complicated, as some include directories may only be populated in the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property, instead of the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property. So it is probably best to check both properties.