# Hooking syscalls in Go

Tags: linux, go, system-calls

I'm trying to hook the fopen syscall in linux using Go.

Normally I would use C for something like this (Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/880278/5572976) but the CTF states that the solution needs to be written in Go.

I've looked at the [syscall](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/) package and basically what I'm looking for is using the following in Go.

```
dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open");
```

EDIT: That's **open**, not fopen.

Comment: This sounds exactly like the sort of question that needs a lot more detail because I am almost sure there are better ways to get to what you *actually* want to accomplish.

Comment: @ZanLynx What I'm trying to accomplish is to hook the fopen syscall globally using LD_PRELOAD and change the output of a file with a specific name. Using libraries mixing C and Go is fine as long as the submitted code is Go.

Comment: You just restated your question for the most part. The only new bit is "change the output of a file with a specific name." Seems more like a job for `inotify`.

Comment: Also you can't hook `fopen` in Go because Go does not even use the C library. When Go makes a system call it makes it directly to the operating system kernel.

Comment: Although I suppose that you could interpose `fopen` with C code and call into Go code from there. Of course then your interpose library has a Go runtime in it which can cause all kinds of problems if you load it into a program that already has a Go runtime.

Comment: I gave you an example of how I would do it in C, and while it is what I'm trying to do I'm not looking for just the solution (I would've used the C code I linked for that) I want to understand how syscall hooking would be implemented in Go.

EDIT: Types this without seeing your responses, sorry.

Comment: Your question text is wrong though. Because fopen is not a syscall.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I meant **open**, not fopen.

Comment: To help people who may become confused by your question, (as I have), please **consistently** correct your question; I assume it should say *open* everywhere, and not a mixture of *fopen* and *open*. Is that correct?

Comment: BTW, `open` as in the question you linked is not a system call either. It is a call to glibc which then makes an actual system call.

Comment: To actually monitor all file access you will need to use inotify to look at a specific file or the audit system or fanotify. Or use SystemTap or kprobe.

Answer (score 1):

try this [Runtime dynamic library loader (dlopen / dlsym) for Go (golang)](https://github.com/rainycape/dl)